# GWT I18n configuration

Tags: java, gwt

I understand that if the gwt application needs to support multiple locale values, all of them should be configured in module xml as

```
 <extend-property name="locale" values="de"/>
 <extend-property name="locale" values="es"/>
```

and then the GWT will decide which locale to load run time using either **query string** or **meta tag in host page**.

But, for the application to support all the locales available, how should i configure in module xml file? Should i add extend-property tag for all the locales or is any other configuration available for this? Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's what you need to do. In the file `com.google.gwt.i18n.CldrLocales.gwt.xml` you can find all locales. Using the list in that file with some smart copy/replace you could create the configuration you require.

But I doubt you really want to do this. It means you get at least ~450(~number of locales) * 6(different supported browsers) permutations or 2700 different html files, which probably would take hours or even days to compile...