# switching locales dynamically?

Tags: java, gwt, internationalization, gxt

I am using GWT/Spring/Hibernate application. I am going to implement internationalization(i18n). my appln should support 5 different languages. i can configure appropriate languages in gwt.xml file and externalize all properties into separate properties file specific to each language. but **i need to provide a combobox where all locales are displayed, based on the selected locale, page should be refreshed.** How can i achieve this?

```
<extend-property name="locale" values="en"/>//i have set for all 5 locales
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am very much novice at GWT, but the following will help you:

1. [GWT I18n configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8561553/767881)
2. [Locales in GWT - DevGuideI18nLocale](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideI18nLocale)
3. [Add Runtime Locales to your moduleXML](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideI18nLocale#RuntimeLocales)
4. [Programmatic Access to Locale Information](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideI18nLocale#LocaleInfo)